# SQL query based on array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array called `$restaurantArray` which contains a selection of restaurant id's.

Is there anyway I can execute a mysql query that will return rows if their id is equal to one of these restaurant ID's in the array?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If so, please show that, as well as how you're interacting with the database.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11181663/1208233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IN with your mysql query.
Just implode the array $restaurantArray into the string, using comma as a delimiter; cover this string with brackets; and use the result string as input to the query. 
Something like

```
// uncomment if data needs to be sanitized
// $restaurantArray = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", $restaurantArray);
$input = '(' . implode(',', $restaurantArray) . ')';
$query = "SELECT from foo WHERE id IN $input";
```

Comment: Vulnerable to injection attacks..

Comment: How is it vulnerable to such attacks if the array comes directly from the database!

Comment: Use this snippet before the DB query.
foreach($restaurantArray as $key=>$value) {
  $restaurantArray[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

Comment: You can never assume these things. Everything must be escaped. Period.

Comment: Seeing `mysql_real_escape_string` is a sign you're doing this wrong. Please use something current like PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I am using PDO as it goes.

Comment: @Ankesh - how would I alter this to randomly select 3 values and 3 values only?

Comment: @Luke, Add "LIMIT 3" to the mysql query.

Comment: That wouldn't be random though?

Comment: You'd use $query = "SELECT from foo WHERE id IN $input ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";